# Probability to pick a sample with similar mean from a population.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The average weight of a mature ear of corn is 175 grams. It's believed that the weight is normally distributed with a standard deviation of 8. From the population, the farmer selects 9 corn. The weights of selected ears are 182, 184, 166, 160, 190, 175, 174, 183 and 170 grams. (Farmer's weighting machine has precision 1 gram and gives integer results.) The sample average is 176. The farmer asks, what is the probability to obtain a sample average as large as 176 if he repeats this experiment?

I tried calculating the standard deviation of the sample
std dev = 9.63

later I considered CDF to calculate the probability as follows:
probability = CDF(176.5) - CDF(175.5)

since, the weighing machine is measuring integer values, I have considered

$175.5 \le 176 < 176.5$

Using the above considerations I am getting $probability = 0.05$ but this is too small for a number that close to the average.

Can someone suggest an alternative approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your reasoning is correct. What is wrong is that the sample mean has the following distribution

$$\overline{X}_9\sim N\left(175;\frac{8^2}{9}\right)$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[175.5\leq \overline{X}_9<176.5]=\Phi\left( \frac{176.5-175}{8}\cdot3 \right)-\Phi\left( \frac{175.5-175}{8}\cdot3 \right)\approx13.87\%$$

The Sample variance is not needed.